# segmentation fault while reading file into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, malloc, nodes, singly-linked-list

In the below given code,
im not able to print the content of a student.txt file. I'm not sure if my add function is not malloc 'ing the contents properly. Any suggestions in my code.

> My struct

```
typedef struct student{
  char *name;
  char *number;
  struct student *previous;
  struct student *next;
}Student;
```

> main.c

```
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *in = fopen("student.txt", "r");
  char name[20];
  char num[20];
  Student *list=NULL;

  /* read file into single linked list */
 while(fscanf(in, "%s %s",name, num)==2) {
        list = add(list,name, num);
 }

  /* print the list */
  printf ("\n\nOriginal list\n********************\n");
  print (list);
```

> list.c

```
Student * add (Student *list, char *name, char *number) {
Student *node = malloc(sizeof(Student));
node->name = strdup(128);

Student *current, *head;
void print (Student *list) {
for(current = head; current ; current=current->next){
                printf("%s", current->name);
}
}

node->number = strdup(8);
if(head==NULL){
current = head = node;
} else {
current = current->next = node;
}
        return list;
}
```

> student.txt

```
John 123 
Walter 456
Selena 789
```

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: `strdup(8);` Wat? Turn on more compiler warnings, like compile with `-Wall` or equivalent. That **must** be a C string pointer, not just a number.

Comment: The `print()` function definition shouldn't be inside the `add()` function.

Comment: There's a lot of problems in this code. `head` is never initialized in your `add` function, so that'll explode too once you fix the `strdup()` stuff. Presumably that should be `current = list` in the `print()` function.

Comment: Tip: Write a little bit of code, then test it, then add more code once you're comfortable that's working correctly. It looks like you slammed out a whole bunch of code here and got it to compile, which is not really a good way of doing it. Now you have multiple problems to diagnose at once.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is very likely the call to `strdup`:

```
strdup(128);
```

The argument to the `strdup` function is the string to duplicate. This should be a pointer to the first character in a null-terminated string.

You tell `strdup` that this pointer is `128` which is usually an invalid address, leading to *undefined behavior* and your crash.

You should be passing `name` instead:

```
strdup(name);
```

You seem to be making this mistake(?) for `number` as well.